# Undefied values from XML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

I'm trying to get all ChildNodes from a element, but for some reason for each Child  got one more undefined "child".

Any help please.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<bookstore>
 <book category="cooking">
   <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
   <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
   <year>2005</year>
   <price>30.00</price>
 </book>
 <book category="children">
  <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
  <author>J K. Rowling</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>29.99</price>
 </book>
 <book category="web">
  <book category="web" cover="paperback">
  <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
  <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
  <year>2003</year>
  <price>39.95</price>
 </book>
</bookstore>

function readxml() {
    xmlHttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "teste.xml", false);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    xmlDoc = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement;

    var a = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("book")[0];
    console.log(a.childElementCount); //Result = 4 OK
    for (i = 0; i < a.childElementCount; i++) {
        var b = a.childNodes[i];
    }
}
```

[image: Image from Debug]

Comment: Elements and nodes are not the same. (nodes include whitespace TextNodes)

Comment: Right now. Your XML is not valid.

Comment: Slaks, you are right, thank you ! I was just crazy here looking to my code, but the problem was the XML

Comment: I change a.childNodes to a.children and solve the problem. er...how can i mark your answer as right?